# Can I add a couple of text files in Xcode for write and read

Tags: macos, xcode

I'm using Xcode for developing in C++ language. Is it possible to add a couple of txt files to write and read from them? It is a very cool feature to test a project in a lot of tests.

Answer (score 3):

Go to File → New File or type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>. Under iOS or OS X select Other and click Next. You will be asked to give a name to that file. Call it `whatever.txt` and you are done.

Comment: This is less than obvious. I would argue a "blank file" template would make this much easier to find.